# What's the best way to create a timezone list to the users using Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework, timezone

I have a trouble with generating a friendly timezone list to the users. For example, you can see a timezone list in google calendar settings. It's an excellent example and I'd like to achieve that.
The list has to be translated in different languages (English, French, Russian, Hebrew). 
In the end, I have to create a key=>value list: key - valid timezones, value - user friendly title.

I use Zend Framework and there is the Zend_Locale class that can be used to retrieve the translated cities for timezone. But there is no English translation there (very strange) and the list for timezone-city relation is different for each language.

So, the question is what the best way to get the data?

Answer (score 0):

There's a static method: Zend_Locale::getTranslationList(), which allows you to use some constants:

- TimezoneToWindows,
- WindowsToTimezone,
- TerritoryToTimezone,
- TimezoneToTerritory,
- CityToTimezone,
- TimezoneToCity.

For descriptions, check: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.locale.functions.html

Comment: That's true, I had tried Zend_Locale::getTranslationList('CityToTimezone', 'en'). It returned me the list of about 18 items. Zend_Locale::getTranslationList('CityToTimezone', 'ru') returned 418 items. I'm confused.